# Mapas Interativos com informações no Rstudio

Tags: ggplot2, r, dplyr

Estou com um mapa montado e já definido por código da localidade e com exibição dos dados por tonalidade de cores.
Utilizei o comando:

```
munipb <- read_municipality(code_muni = 'PB')
```

Estou com 2 variáveis na planilha chamadas de; "code_muni" e "quantidade produzida".
Consegui montar um mapa que apresenta o nível de produção por região.

Utilizando o comando:

```
produtox <- inner_join(munipb, produtox,by= "code_muni")

produtoxplot <- ggplot(produtox)+
geom_sf(aes(fill=produtox))
```

Resultado:
[image: Resultado final]

Entretanto, preciso demonstrar os valores dentro do próprio mapa com um comando que faça isso ao passar o mouse em cima de alguma região, aparecendo uma descrição simples como: nome do local e quantidade produzida. dentro do próprio R.
Dessa Maneira:[image: mapa ideal]

Vi alguns fazendo isso utilizando o comando `readOGR`, mas não rodou no meu computador e outras formas de fazer com `leaflet` - salvo engano - precisam dos dados de uma maneira totalmente diferente.

Fico grato se puderem me ajudar. Apresentar os dados como na primeira imagem é um pouco complicado. E a forma da última imagem seria o ideal

Comment: Dê uma olhada no ggplotly https://plotly.com/ggplot2/maps-sf/